# Sharepoint 2013 Online Public Website Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

As noticed ofice365 sharepoint doesnt support creation of subsites, and using sharepoint designer i cannot be able to create a publishing subsite as it deletes it immediately. I wanted to create multiple pages but how do i do so in such a way that it appears in the url as eg https://myonlinesite.com as default and  https://myonlinesite.com/de/ for the other language

Comment: Look in to a managed navigation, it uses a structure of friendly URLs that should help you accomplish what you want

Comment: its office 365 sharepoint and i dont have the option navigation in my site settings, its E3

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just click "Edit links" on the start page of the public web and then create and drag-n-drop the items to create a hierarchy.

This is a very easy way to build a hiearchy in the URL but still keep the pages stored flat in a library

Comment: I can use that to create links and sub-links, but if i add a page and set the link to /de/contact it writes the url as /de-contact

Comment: I don't follow, first create pages on the top level. You then get a navigation node for it. Then drag-n-drop the navigation node to your wanted place in the hiearchy